# Performclick in Andengine

Tags: click, andengine

I am developing a game with Andengine and I have a problem. I want to use PerformClick() function on sprites that have touch areas but sprites have no methods like PerformClick(). How can I simulate a click action in Andengine?

Any help would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: try this? http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/simulate-touch-events-t12444.html

Comment: thanks for the answer but it gave error, it doesnt work in GLES1. I  went for the long solution and run the functions in specific time in order that I want.

Comment: Can you post how you solved this then?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a sprite like a button like this:

```
mySprite = new Sprite(posX, posYy, mySpriteTextureRegion,
                vertexBufferObjectManager) {
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY) {
                if (pEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    //Do something
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

Hope it can help you!